# algorithm moves the array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I can not figure out an algorithm for this task, maybe you have an idea?
Task: Move the array to the array in the first half would be all the elements of the odd lines and the second all elements of the pair of lines.
The simplest option would be to move elements to another array, as it could make one using temp variable?

```
Input data array  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
output data array = {2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is this homework? If not, use `std::stable_partition()`:

```
struct IsEven {
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& v) const { return v % 2 == 0; }
};

int* arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int* mid = std::stable_partition(arr, arr+8, IsEven());
```

If it is a homework, then your instructor probably expects you to write the algorithm. If you don't have to maintain the ordering as in the input sequence then you can do it rather efficiently:

1. Find the **first** element that **doesn't** satisfy the predicate (i.e., is *odd*).
2. Find that **last** element that **does** satisfy the predicate (i.e., is *even*)
3. swap the two elements.
4. Repeat, starting from the positions you just found, until the two positions meet.
5. The point where the two positions meet is the **middle** of the partition, where even numbers stop and odd numbers begin.

This is roughly how `std::partition()` works. If you do have to maintain the relative ordering in the input array then you can still do it in-place, but it will be faster if you use a temporary buffer. Copy the elements that don't match the predicate into that buffer, and squeeze in place those that do. Finally bring back in the elements that don't match, at the end of the array, in order.

Comment: if he has trouble figuring this out, your answer will probably be to advanced :)

Comment: This doesn't preserve the relative order of elements within each partition. Also, it relies on the values of the elements, whereas the OP was referring to odd- and even-numbered positions in the array.

Comment: @Marcelo correct. Fixed to use `stable_partition()` instead. Also, OP @Valisimo, did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes it`s homework. Thank you for your sample, but I need an algorithm and then make it a function which maintains an array (in c + +),try to figure out your algorithm

Comment: I think the question may have to to with the indexes of the values rather than the actual values.

Comment: the described version of stable_partition will not reserve relative order though, eg. the first odd element will be inserted after the next found odd element.

Comment: @Valisimo wait, my bad: the algorithm above _will_ partition the array but will not maintain the ordering. If you want to maintain the ordering then you will probably need a temporary buffer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm  reading this question such that the output array should have the elements at even indices followed by those at odd indices, though I may be incorrect.

If not, then this is how I would do it.

```
template<typename T>
void moveValues(const T[] input, T[] output, std::size_t length)
{
    int current outputIndex = 0;
    if (length > 1)  // in case we have a single element array.
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i+=2)
        {
            output[++outputIndex] = input[i];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j+=2)
    {
        output[++outputIndex] = input[j];
    }
    assert(outputIndex == length);  // should have filled up array
}
```

Comment: This approach assumes to have two distinct arrays, `input` and `output`. What if the arrays are identical? At least, there should be a check for this case. And additionally, in case, a "stable" version could be provided to perform the operation on a single array (with less performance maybe). BTW, I think you don't need two `for` loops for this approach: The `for` loops could be joined together.

Comment: 1. I suppose it's possible the arrays are the same or overlap.  For a production routine on something going up in the space shuttle, I'd probably check.  For a SO homework question, I'll do without it.

Comment: 2. Yes, I'm sure it's possible.  it probably involves doing various swaps.  I was aiming for simple and straightforward first.

Comment: 3. Same as above.  I'm sure it can be done in a single for loop (keeping an index in the second half of the array, but IMO it would not be as simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* *********************************************************************** */
/*              Author: Bigyan Shrestha                                    */
/*              Description: C++ source code for arranging even numbers    */
/*                           numbers of an array to one  half and odd      */
/*                           numbers to the other half.                    */
/* *********************************************************************** */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline bool isEven( int value ){
    if( value % 2 == 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

inline void swap( int sourceIndex, int destIndex, int **sourceArray ) {
    int temp;
    temp = (*sourceArray)[sourceIndex];
    (*sourceArray)[sourceIndex] = (*sourceArray)[destIndex];
    (*sourceArray)[destIndex] = temp;
}

void displayArray( int *sourceArray, int size ){
    for( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ ) {
        cout << sourceArray[i] << "  " ;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

int main( void ){

    int size;
    int *input;
    int evenIndex = 0;  // for keeping track of even numbers

    cout << "Enter the size of input array" << endl ;
    cin  >> size;

    input = new int[size];

    for( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ ) {
        cout << "Please enter the input value ( " << size-i << " remaining )" << endl;
        cin >> input[i] ;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Original Input Array " << endl;
    displayArray( input,size );
    cout << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i <size ; i++ ) {
        if( isEven(input[i]) && i > evenIndex ) {
            for( int j = i ; j > evenIndex; j-- ){
                swap( j, j-1, &input);
            }
            ++evenIndex;
        }
    }

    cout << "Modified Array " << endl;
    displayArray( input,size );
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```